# How do all react requests go to the index.js file?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a bit confusing how routing works with react-router.

Normally when a request comes to the server for a request like:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/file
```

A request will make it to the server for that file, and then the framework will handle the request.

With react router, how does this work?   Do things somehow get intercepted at the client side (browser) and then only a request to index.html will be made to the actual web server?

I'm assuming somehow the request to /path/to/file gets trapped by javascript and only a request to index.html makes it to the server, but how does it do this?

Answer (score 0):

React router is a client side router, so when we do configs for nginx or any webserver in general with react router we specify and send only 1 file known as index.html and then the JavaScript code provided by react router figures out which component to serve by looking at the path and history of the browser.

So no matter which path you request it's indirectly index.html which gets the request but with a different path which then figures out what to do.

Answer (score 0):

One part of the answer is looking at the [basename prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) of the Router. Everything that comes after that is handled at client side as the location corresponding to the app current state.

Another part of the answer is that when using BroswerRouter (as opposed to a HashRouter that uses the # separator in the URL before the local app state), the server has to serve the app "index.html" for any route that does not correspond to an actual static ressource or an API route. This is usually treated as the fallback behaviour of the server.

When using BrowserRouter, if your server base url is http://example.com/app, and your current app state is /user/12, that makes the current browser url http://example.com/app/user/12. If you refresh your browser, it will make a request to http://example.com/app/user/12 and your server app has to answer with the index.html of the app. When loaded, react router will interpret the current state as /user/12, following the configured basename.

When using a HashRouter, with the same server base url and app state, the current browser url would be http://example.com/app/#/user/12 and when refreshing the page, the browser would make a request to http://example.com/app/